# How to chain login gates in Hapi.js?

Tags: javascript, json, validation, hapi.js, joi

I am trying to validate a JSON sent via POST request. I am using JOI validator for hapijs. The JSON cannot have both password and access token together but if the user is guest then this check is ignored.

```
validate: {
      payload: Joi.object({
        isGuest: Joi.boolean().required(),
        username: Joi.string().when('isGuest', { is: false, then: Joi.required() }),
        password: Joi.string().alphanum(),
        accessToken: Joi.string().alphanum(),
      }).options({ allowUnknown: true }).xor('password', 'accessToken'),
    },
```

The logic I am trying to implement would look something like this.

`OR('isGuest', XOR(AND('username','password'), 'accessToken'))`

I cant figure out how to implement this using the tools available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`without`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectwithoutkey-peers)

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  isGuest: Joi.boolean(),
  password: Joi.string().alphanum(),
  accessToken: Joi.string().alphanum(),
}).without('isGuest', ['password', 'accessToken'])
  .without('password', 'accessToken');
```

Here are the test cases

```
const object1 = { isGuest: true }
console.log(Joi.validate(object1, schema)); // pass

const object2 = { password: 'asdfads' }
console.log(Joi.validate(object2, schema)); // pass

const object3 = { accessToken: 'asdfads' }
console.log(Joi.validate(object3, schema)); // pass

const object4 = { isGuest: true, password: "asdf" }
console.log(Joi.validate(object4, schema)); // fail

const object5 = { isGuest: true, accessToken: "asdf" }
console.log(Joi.validate(object5, schema)); // fail

const object6 = { password: "asdf", accessToken: "asdf" }
console.log(Joi.validate(object6, schema)); // fail
```

---

If you are interested in the value as well, you can use this schema

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  isGuest: Joi.boolean(),
  password: Joi.string().alphanum(),
  accessToken: Joi.string().alphanum(),
}).when(Joi.object({
  isGuest: Joi.boolean().required().valid(true),
  password: Joi.string().alphanum().optional(),
  accessToken: Joi.string().alphanum().optional(),
}), {
    then: Joi.object({
      password: Joi.string().alphanum().optional(),
      accessToken: Joi.string().alphanum().optional(),
    }),
    otherwise: Joi.object({
      password: Joi.string().alphanum(),
      accessToken: Joi.string().alphanum(),
    }).xor('password', 'accessToken'),
  });

const object1 = { isGuest: true }
console.log(Joi.validate(object1, schema)); // pass

const object4 = { isGuest: true, password: "asdf" }
console.log(Joi.validate(object4, schema)); // pass

const object5 = { isGuest: true, accessToken: "asdf" }
console.log(Joi.validate(object5, schema)); // pass

const object7 = { isGuest: true, password: "abc", accessToken: "1234" }
console.log(Joi.validate(object7, schema)); // pass

const object2 = { isGuest: false, password: 'asdfads' }
console.log(Joi.validate(object2, schema)); // pass

const object31 = { isGuest: false, accessToken: 'asdfads' }
console.log(Joi.validate(object31, schema)); // pass

const object21 = { password: 'asdfads' }
console.log(Joi.validate(object21, schema)); // pass

const object3 = { accessToken: 'asdfads' }
console.log(Joi.validate(object3, schema)); // pass

console.log('Failure cases');

const object11 = { isGuest: false }
console.log(Joi.validate(object11, schema)); // fail

const object6 = { isGuest: false, password: "asdf", accessToken: "asdf" }
console.log(Joi.validate(object6, schema)); // fail
```

Comment: This only takes the presence of `isGuest` into account, not the actual value. The following should also pass, but does not in your example: `{ "isGuest": true, "password": "abc", "accessToken": "1234" }`

Comment: @Ankh Updated with the new schema

Comment: For `username`: You can add to the schema in all the `when`clause and make it `required` in  the `otherwise` schema